# RMI: is a remote object the same as the server?

Tags: rmi

Some tutorials of RMI speaks about client and server and other about callers and remote objects. So can I say the caller=client and remote object=server. Maybe a stupid question but I need some confirmation or a better explanation.

Answer (score -1):

> So can I say the caller=client and remote object=server.

Yes.